# IBM TWS Java API queryFilter

Tags: java, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

How to find job stream using job name? When I use this code:

```
                QueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilter();                    
                queryFilter.setFilter(JobStreamFilters.JOB_NAME, "JOBNAME");



                QueryResult queryResult = model.queryTWSObject(JobStream.class, queryFilter, 25, null);
                QueryContext queryContext = queryResult.getQueryContext();
```

I get the list of all applications from AD. How to get only this application where job is residing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JobStreamFilters.JOB_NAME is applicable only to IBM Workload Scheduler distributed, as indicated in the javadoc:

> The job name filter. String parameter. (This filter can be used only with a TWS Distributed engine.)

Try using JobStreamFilters.JOB_DEFINITION_TASK instead.